# Multiple fonts in asp.net website in single div

Tags: asp.net, fonts

I am developing a exam software where I need some help in fonts implementation. I provide user an option to add Hindi font content i.e. Kurtidev 10 and apply CSS to that div:

```
<style type="text/css">
    @font-face
    {
        font-family: "My Custom Font";
        src: url('font/Kruti_Dev_010.ttf') format("truetype");
    }
    .customClass
    {
        font-family: "My Custom Font" !important;
        font-size: 18px !important;
    }
```

but if user add any of the english font in that text then it convert that Hindi text into the Kurtidev 10 too.

I need help that how can I set that only Hindi font take that CSS, if any other font it found then it will not be converted.

Comment: is there any solution that we can add 5-6 fonts in the application and if any of the font found from them its get converted